# How to add the selected ListBox Item along with it's price on a receipt to be printed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I connected the `ListBox` with a table from a local database, with two columns:
name and price.

I want the `Item` selected from the `ListBox` to be send. The `Item`'s name and price should be added to the price of the next selected `Item` and the receipt should be printed.

How can I do that?

Comment: This question is too broad and requires a very detailed and lengthy answer. You will get more help if you attempt to implement this up to the point where you hit a blocker and have a more specific question to ask. I recommend that you start by googling for a potential design and try to code it.

Comment: I've managed to complete half of this really long question of mine, now I need to add print functionality to WinForm application, how to make the size of the printed document as of a narrow bill sized page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to add more logic to fit your specific needs but the below code should serve as general method to achieve what you are wanting to accomplish.

```
    public class DBRowObject { // The object that will be stored in the "DataSource" of the ComboBox
        public int iPrice = 0;
        public string strName = "";

        public DBRowObject(int price, string name) {
            iPrice = price;
            strName = name;
        }

        public override string ToString() // This means the combo box will display the name
        {
            return strName;
        }

    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<DBRowObject> lsRows = new List<DBRowObject>(){new DBRowObject(3,"Bob"),new DBRowObject(2,"Sam"),new DBRowObject(5,"John")};
        this.cbCombo.DataSource = lsRows;
    }
    public DBRowObject prevSelected = null;
    private void cbCombo_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBRowObject dbrCurr = (DBRowObject)cbCombo.SelectedItem;

        if (prevSelected != null) {
            dbrCurr.iPrice += prevSelected.iPrice;
        }

        // TODO Display information about these objects and perform various other tasks

        prevSelected = dbrCurr;
    }
```

Comment: I managed to get the selected item's name and price in variables using the following code

Comment: private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e

conn.Open();

String Query = "Select * from ansarilab where lab_name= '" + listBox1.Text +  "' ;";

SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);

SqlDataReader myReader;

myReader = command1.ExecuteReader();  

 while (myReader.Read())
             {
 
string var = Convert.ToString(myReader["lab_name"]);
 
int var1 = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["price"]);

 TextBox1.Text = var;

 TextBox2.Text = var1.ToString();

 result += var1;

 TextBox3.Text = result.ToString();
        }

Comment: Now I need to add a print document in the program and get the values from these three variables on it, and I want to add print functionality to it, how can I do that ? please help and thank you for helping in such a broad question

Comment: @AliMohsin Take a look at this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/print-dialog-and-print-preview-tools-using-entire-windows-form-to-print2/